# ENVI Changes the Projection of the output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, envi

After I have finished my Object-Oriented Classification, I open my result in ArcMap and I see that ENVI changed my Projection. Now the images are really in different places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's tricky, assuming they were "Okay" on ENVI, All you have to do now is reproject your output in your wanted projection. Don't use anything special though :

1. Access them via ArcCatalog.
2. Right click on your Output and define your spatial reference
   (overwrite ENVI's)